# How to remove small capitals when using biblatex with babel in french?

Tags: biblatex

When I use `biblatex` with `authoryear` style, everything appears as I want. However, when I add `\usepackage[french]{babel}`, the citations and references are written is small capitals. Is there a way to remove the small capitals?

MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{abel2018,
  title = {Estimates of {{Global Bilateral Migration Flows}} by {{Gender}} between 1960 and 2015},
  author = {Abel, Guy J.},
  date = {2018-09},
  journaltitle = {International Migration Review},
  shortjournal = {International Migration Review},
  volume = {52},
  pages = {809--852},
  doi = {10.1111/imre.12327},
  url = {http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1111/imre.12327},
  urldate = {2019-12-14},
  langid = {english},
  number = {3}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{abel2018} and \parencite{abel2018}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

What I have:

[image]

What I would like to have (with accents on "Références"):

[image]

Comment: The small caps correspond to the  typographical tradition in French, as months names  do not use an initial capital letter. .

Comment: okay but suppose I want to remove them, how could I do it?

Comment: Probably related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301571/134144

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438423/35864 help?

Comment: @leandriis the solution in this other post works on overleaf, but it does not when I use it in R markdown. I know this is not a part of the question but maybe you have an idea of why it does not work? The error is: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.62 \DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}` (I put this line in a tex file that I called in YAML). If this is not suited for tex stackexchange, I will ask it on Stackoverflow

Comment: @moewe same answer as for leandriis

Comment: R markdown probably executes that command too early, i.e. when `biblatex` isn't loaded yet. (R markdown and `biblatex` can be a bit tricky: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449191/35864)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301571/134144 and [Keep lowercase in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438423/35864) the correct solution to stop `biblatex`'s French language module from typesetting family names in small caps is to add

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
```

in the preamble after `biblatex` was loaded.

---

As it turned out in the comments the OP is using R markdown, which loads `biblatex` semi-automatically. Adding the line above to the preamble apparently generates an error of the form

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.62 \DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
```

which suggests that this preamble code is executed before `biblatex` is loaded.

In that case

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}}
```

may help. Those two lines defer the execution of `\DefineBibliographyExtras` until the end of the preamble, at which point R markdown should have loaded `biblatex` so that the command is available.

This works in the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}}

\usepackage[backend = biber, style = authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson} and \parencite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Sigfridsson et Ryde 1998 and (Sigfridsson et Ryde 1998)" no small caps]

Comment: this works both in overleaf and in R markdown, thanks