# R Markdown: BibLaTeX duplicate Bibliography When adding to ToC

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, rmarkdown

an R markdown file `index.rmd`:

```yaml
---
title: title
author: author
bibliography: bib.bib
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: true
    pandoc_args: ["--biblatex"]
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[]{biblatex}
---

# heading
lorem \autocite{mycite}
```

Results in:

[image: pdf page with table of content with the first section, and references not included in table of contents]

I want to add the `references` section to ToC. I tried half a dozen of solutions, one of which is [Bibliography not in ToC when using biblatex/biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67153/bibliography-not-in-toc-when-using-biblatex-biber).

Much like all other solutions, adding `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]` resulted in duplicating the references section:
[image]

Is there a way to suppress the references section entirely to configure it manually?

(Being able to rename the references section would be nice, too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following:

```
\section*{Works Cited} % adds section
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Works Cited} % adds section to table of content
\defbibheading{bibliography} % replaces bibliography heading with nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Works Cited}]
```

would be the correct choice. But with Rmarkdown/`pandoc` the bibliography is produced automatically for you, so adding a `\printbibliography` in the code yourself produces a second bibliography.

The `pandoc` template located at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex suggests that there is no way to inject options like `heading=bibintoc` into the `\printbibliography` produced by `pandoc`. But it is possible to set the bibliography title with

```yaml
biblio-title: Works Cited
```

**If** `pandoc` does not sanitise the input you give there with braces, it may be possible to inject options that way

```yaml
biblio-title: Works Cited, heading=bibintoc
```

I'm not sure if that works, but even if did, it would be an incredibly dirty trick.

---

With a modern `biblatex` version (at least v3.12 from 2019-08-17) you can add

```
\DeclarePrintbibliographyDefaults{heading=bibintoc}
```

to your preamble to make `heading=bibintoc` the default for all `\printbibliography` calls.

If that command is not available because you `biblatex` is too old you can add

```
\csletcs{blx@head@bibliography}{blx@head@bibintoc}
```

to your preamble. That makes the default bibliography heading `bibliography` have the same definition as `bibintoc`.

---

If I understand correctly it should be possible to use

```yaml
output:
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: biblatex
biblio-style: numeric
biblatexoptions: [backend=biber, maxbibnames=999]
```

to have Rmarkdown/`pandoc` load `biblatex` for you instead of adding it via `\usepackage[]{biblatex}` and the `--biblatex` option.

Compare for example [Using biblatex with R Markdown](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449191/35864).

Comment: I couldn't get `biblatex-chicago` to work with the piece of code at the end.

Comment: @simohamed Ah yes, `biblatex-chicago` is a special case since it should generally be loaded via its own wrapper package `\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}` instead of `\usepackage[style=<style>]{biblatex}`. You could try `citation_package: biblatex`+`biblio-style: chicago-authordate`/`biblio-style: chicago-notes`, but this may not get everything right. Maybe that's worth a feature request to the pandoc developers?

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly not ideal, but you can try an approach like

```
\printbibliography[label=references, heading=bibintoc, title={Works Cited}]
\let\printbibliography\relax
```

to

1. Insert the list of references where you want,
2. Make sure that whenever pandoc tries to re-insert the list of references, nothing will be displayed.