Inserting citation within Latex figure caption
I am writing my thesis and am struggling to create a citation within Latex code. I get following error:
Warning: LaTeX Warning: Citation `2023TylerIyengarTestingRobustnessANES' on page 12 undefined on input line 194. Warning: LaTeX Warning: Citation `2023TylerIyengarTestingRobustnessANES' on page 12 undefined on input line 194. Warning: LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
So far, I have always cited in my markdown document via [@citationkey], without issue. However, in my following figure I cannot achieve a successful reference:
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth]{resources/p_thermometer.pdf}
\caption[ANES Feeling Thermometer Time Series]{ANES Feeling Thermometer between 1978 and 2020. Grouped by group bias: feelings towards own party (in-party) and feelings towards opposing party (out-party). Retrieved via {\cite{2023TylerIyengarTestingRobustnessANES}} and visually recreated.}
\label{fig:Feeling-Thermometer-via-Tyler-Iyengar-2023}
\end{figure}

I can guarantee that the citation key is correct and included in my bibliography file. I also tried protecting the \cite command (either via \protect or {}), without success. For testing purposes I tried inserting [@2023TylerIyengarTestingRobustnessANES] after the Latex code and it works. My YAML looks as follows:
---
title: "Thesis"
author: ""
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    output_file: "thesis_output_file.pdf"
    number_sections: true
    toc: false
    toc-title: "Table of Contents"
bibliography: resources/thesis-references.bib
geometry: "left = 2.5cm, right = 2.5cm, top = 2.5cm, bottom = 2.5cm"
fontsize: 12pt
link-citations: true
csl: resources/apa.csl
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{hyperref}
  - \newcommand{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{Figure \ref*{#1}}}
  - \usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf,labelsep=colon]{caption}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \pagenumbering{gobble}
  - \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
  - \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
  - \newcounter{romanpage}
  - \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
---

MRE:
---
title: "MRE StackOverflow"
author: "PD"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    output_file: "thesis_output_file.pdf"
bibliography: testbib.bib
---

#```#{=latex}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.50\textwidth]{resources/p_thermometer.pdf}
\caption[ANES Feeling Thermometer Time Series]{American National Election Studies' Feeling Thermometer in a time series between 1978 and 2020. Grouped by group bias: feelings towards own party (in-party) and feelings towards opposing party (out-party). Retrieved via {\cite{2023TylerIyengarTestingRobustnessANES}} and visually recreated.}
\label{fig:Feeling-Thermometer-via-Tyler-Iyengar-2023}
\end{figure}
#```#

Needs a testbib.bib file with the citationkey 2023TylerIyengarTestingRobustnessANES.

Either bibtex/biber hasn't run or has run with errors, seeing 2023TylerIyengarTestingRobustnessANES would help with the latter, but I think the issue is you don't appear to specify a \bibliographystyle or equivalent biblatex style, while you do have a csl specified which bibtex/biblatex cannot directly use.

Thanks for your response. What's the difference between csl and \bibliographystyle? I'm not too versed in the Latex way of referencing and am thankful that Markdown and bookdown kinda make it easy for me. Is my issue then simply a limitation of this approach?

You appear to be specifying a CSL with csl: resources/apa.csl, but CSLs are not generally supported by bibtex/biblatex (see Citation Style Language (CSL)), instead they have their own bibliography styles which fulfil the same purpose.
In general not all biblatex styles exist as CSLs and vice versa, but assuming apa.cls is the latest American Psychological Association citation stlye
  citation_package: biblatex
  biblio-style: apa

should work (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449210/106162) and give you the closest match to the current APA style (see these examples).

Hi, this is the answer, yes. Tried it earlier as well but opted out of specifically using biblatex because it changes quite a bit of my setup (links, style for some reason) and broke a few other elements as well. It needed quite a few adjustments and I didn't want to change my entire YAML for one citation. But I did see that the caption within a figure included the in-text citation when I made these adjustments. Thanks.
